# Point coordinates of zoomed area highchart shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, shiny, zooming

I have this scatter plot where I want to zoom in an area and then subset a table to show only the data from the subsetted points. The first step is done by zoomType = "xy", but I'm having troubles on the second step. Could anyone give me  a hint on how can I access the upper left and bottom right points coordinates of the zoomed area, so I can subset the table?

Thank you!

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      


  dscars <- round(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu = c(1, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2)), 2)
  dsplan <- round(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = c(3, 4), Sigma = matrix(c(2,.5,2,2),2)), 2)
  dstrck <- round(mvrnorm(n = 15, mu = c(5, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1),2)), 2)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "scatter", zoomType = "xy") %>% 
      hc_tooltip(
        useHTML = T,
        enabled = F,
        pointFormat = paste0("<span style=\"color:{series.color};\">{series.options.icon}</span>",
                             "{series.name}: <b>[{point.x}, {point.y}]</b><br/>")
      ) %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dscars)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("car")),icon = fa_icon("car"), name = "car") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dsplan)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("plane")),icon = fa_icon("plane"), name = "plane") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dstrck)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("truck")),icon = fa_icon("truck"), name = "truck") %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) 


  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$legendClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked into the legend and selected series ", input$legendClicked, ".")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**2nd Try**
I tried something like:

```
selectionfunction<- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('range', [event.xAxis, event.yAxis]);}")
```

with:

```
hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list( selection=selectionfunction ))) 

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$range, {
    outputText <<- paste0("x= ", input$range[1],"y= " ,input$range[2]) 
  })
  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
```

But it seems to me that the function selectionfunction is not called when I zoom the plot.

**Almost a good solution**
I found a almost functional solution:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")
library("MASS")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      


  dscars <- round(mvrnorm(n = 20, mu = c(1, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,0,0,1),2)), 2)
  dsplan <- round(mvrnorm(n = 10, mu = c(3, 4), Sigma = matrix(c(2,.5,2,2),2)), 2)
  dstrck <- round(mvrnorm(n = 15, mu = c(5, 1), Sigma = matrix(c(1,.5,.5,1),2)), 2)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      


    selectionfunction <- JS("function(event) {
                                 Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked2', [event.xAxis[0].min , event.xAxis[0].max , event.yAxis[0].min , event.yAxis[0].max ] );}")



    highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "scatter", zoomType = "xy", events= list(selection=selectionfunction)) %>% 
      hc_tooltip(
        useHTML = T,
        enabled = F,
        pointFormat = paste0("<span style=\"color:{series.color};\">{series.options.icon}</span>",
                             "{series.name}: <b>[{point.x}, {point.y}]</b><br/>")
      ) %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dscars)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("car")),icon = fa_icon("car"), name = "car") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dsplan)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("plane")),icon = fa_icon("plane"), name = "plane") %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = list.parse2(as.data.frame(dstrck)),marker = list(symbol = fa_icon_mark("truck")),icon = fa_icon("truck"), name = "truck")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")


  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2],input$canvasClicked[3], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked2, {
    outputText <<- paste0(input$canvasClicked2[1]," ",input$canvasClicked2[2]," ",input$canvasClicked2[3]," ",input$canvasClicked2[4]) 
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The axis boundaries are correctly printed but with 1 step delay. Can someone help?

**Final Solution**

I found a solution by working on the JS function:

```
  selectionfunction1 <- JS("function(event) {
                              var x_axis_min,x_axis_max,y_axis_min,y_axis_max;

                              if (event.xAxis) {
                                x_axis_min = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].min, 2),
                                x_axis_max = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.xAxis[0].max, 2);
                              }else{
                                x_axis_min = 'reset',
                                x_axis_max = 'reset';
                              }
                              if (event.yAxis) {
                                y_axis_min = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.yAxis[0].min, 2),
                                y_axis_max = Highcharts.numberFormat(event.yAxis[0].max, 2);
                              }else{
                                y_axis_min = 'reset',
                                y_axis_max = 'reset';
                              }
                              Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClickedxmin', x_axis_min);
                              Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClickedxmax', x_axis_max);
                              Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClickedymin', y_axis_min);
                              Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClickedymax', y_axis_max);
    }")
```

Comment: In Highcharts you should be able to use axis event [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) and then loop over points and check if they are visible or have their `x`s and `y`s inside new extremes. I do not know if this is possible via R. [Selection](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection) event might be useful here too.

Comment: Be carefull, the fontawesome plugin have a little detail/bug: the icons are showed with a some offset. This can be noted when you make a zoom the hover effect (the circle, the real point) is not behind the icon